# Is there an easier way to do this with Lazy<T>?

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

I was trying to find a concrete example online but I couldn't find one that also used one of the class' other attributes.

So, can this be done more succinctly with a `Lazy<T>` object?

```
    public string BrandAbbreviation { get; set; }

    private bool _brandPopulated = false;
    private CommonBrand _brand;
    public CommonBrand Brand
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_brandPopulated){
                _brand = new CommonBrand(BrandAbbreviation);
                _brandPopulated = true;
            }

            return _brand;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use the constructor of `Lazy<T>` which accepts an initialization `func<T>`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're not setting `_brandPopulated` to true anywhere. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Wasn't worried too much about that as it was just an example - I did update it just in case someone else tries to use the same approach and needs the boolean for something.

Thanks

Comment: @Rotem The constructor won't let me use other attributes in the class - that's the same issue I had when trying to use MainMa's suggestion.  I was hoping there was a way around this.

Answer (score 3):

### Removing a field

Even without `Lazy<T>`, you may shorten the code by removing the redundant variable:

```
public string BrandAbbreviation { get; set; }

private CommonBrand _brand;

public CommonBrand Brand
{
    get
    {
        if (!this._brand == null)
        {
            this._brand = new CommonBrand(this.BrandAbbreviation);
        }

        return this._brand;
    }
}
```

Removing `_brandPopulated` has not only the benefit of removing a few LOCs, but also makes the code clearer. By having a separate field which flags whether `_brand` is set, you could potentially have situations you don't handle in your code (and which are not obvious to handle right):

- `_brandPopulated` is `false`, but `_brand` is initialized to a value. Should we forget about the previous value? Should we keep it?
- `_brandPopulated` is `true`, but `_brand` is `null`. How do you handle that? Do you check for `null` after checking for `_brandPopulated`? Or maybe you don't, and risk encountering an ugly `NullReferenceException`?

### Introducing (or not) `Lazy<T>`

You can indeed use `Lazy<T>`, which makes it possible to make the code even shorter:

```
public string BrandAbbreviation { get; set; }

private readonly Lazy<CommonBrand> _brand;

public ClassName() // Replace by the name of the actual class.
{
    this._brand = new Lazy<CommonBrand>(() => new CommonBrand(this.BrandAbbreviation));
}

public CommonBrand Brand
{
    get
    {
        return this._brand.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but got some build errors.  That's what I ran into before posting this as well ... apparently, you can't use other attributes from the instance itself in Lazy instantiations.  I was hoping there was something I was missing but maybe not....

Comment: Errors from the build:

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type
Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

When I switch it over to your initial suggestion, it builds fine.

Comment: @user107775: I see. No, it has nothing to do with `Lazy<T>`, but with the fact that I did the initialization directly when creating the field: the initialization code should be moved to the constructor. I edited the answer.

Comment: Your reasoning about the bool flag is incomplete.  What about the case where `null` is a valid value? I'd also argue that by making `null` a magic value you're removing clarity.

Comment: @MetaFight: looking at the actual usage of the variable by the OP, it doesn't seem like `null` would be a valid value, thus my recommandation to remove the redundant boolean.

Comment: @MainMa the problem with moving it to the class constructor is that it no longer becomes "lazy instantiation" right?  Since you're instantiating it right as soon as the class is initialized then the cost is burned right up front and there's no longer the savings of waiting until the actual attribute is used .... unless I'm overlooking something about Lazy<T>?

Comment: @user107775 what's passed to the `Lazy<T>` constructor is a generator function.  It does not build the `CommonBrand` object until executed, which happens the first time you reference `Lazy<T>.Value`.